# Flutter TextFormField not updating it's value

Tags: flutter, timepicker, textformfield

i'va made a TimePicker that will pop up when user taps on `textFormField` it's working fine but the only problem is that i want to update `textFormField` value by the one selected from `timePicker`
I've declared a `controller` and initilize a `selectedTimer`

```
  TimeOfDay selectedTime = TimeOfDay(hour: 0, minute: 0);
  TextEditingController _timeController = TextEditingController();
```

And this is the code of `TextFormField`

```
 TextFormField(
      controller: _timeController,
      onTap: () {
         FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
         _selectTime(context);
      },
  ),
```

And this is the code for the method `_selectTime`

```
_selectTime(BuildContext context) async {
    final TimeOfDay? timeOfDay = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: selectedTime,
      initialEntryMode: TimePickerEntryMode.dial,
    );
    if (timeOfDay != null && timeOfDay != selectedTime) {
      setState(() {
        selectedTime = timeOfDay;
        TextEditingValue(text: timeOfDay.toString());
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Where are you set the selected time '_controller'?

Comment: Can you include the full widget?

Answer (score 1):

Do as follows:

```
_timeController.text=timeOfDay.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 selectTime(BuildContext context) async {
final TimeOfDay? timeOfDay = await showTimePicker(
  context: context,
  initialTime: selectedTime,
  initialEntryMode: TimePickerEntryMode.dial,
);
if (timeOfDay != null && timeOfDay != selectedTime) {
  setState(() {
    selectedTime = timeOfDay;
    _timeController.text=timeOfDay.toString();
    TextEditingValue(text: timeOfDay.toString());
  });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

remove this line `TextEditingValue(text: timeOfDay.toString());`

and replace by this `_timeController.text = selectedTime.toString();`